# GetElementbyID not showing for IE.Dcoument (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a webscraping program in Visual Studio 2019 using VB.Net Framework but I'm running into an issue. I have the below code to locate an open IE window so that I can manipulate it. The issue I'm running into is when I use IE.Document. the list that appears does not show getelementsbyid. Here is a snippet of my code, it's able to find the appropriate IE window and bring it into focus but I need to be able to manipulate the elements on the page.

I have also added the Com References
Microsoft HTML Object Library
Microsoft Internet Control

```
Dim SWS as new SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim IE as SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

For Each IE in SWS
     If IE.locationName = "XXXXXXXX" Then Exit For 
NExt 

'To get focus on IE window
IE.Visible = False
IE.Visible = True

IE.Document.
```

I would appreciate any insight since I'm at a loss as to why getelementbyid won't show.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can try to refer to the code example below that may help you to get/ set values.

If you want to set data then refer to the line below.

```
IE.Document.All.Item("fname").Value = "ABC"
```

If you want to fetch data then refer to the line below.

```
Console.WriteLine(IE.Document.All.Item("fname").Value)
```